# jquery addclass to next div and remove it from actual div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I would need to implement some sort of news slider. this is how it should work:

- a container div
- 3 absolute positioned divs with different z-index to have them stacked one on top of the other (the visibility should be one at a time)
- a button which will add a class to the NEXT div in line (i will manage the visibility with css3)

here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/xqLXt/ and my actual js

```
var parentheight = $("#wrapper").parent().height();
$(".wrap").height(parentheight);

$('button.mybutton').click(function() {
  $(this).next('div').addClass('next');
})
```

the actual js give the class .next to the first div .. what i want it do is to give the class "next" to the second div on the click of the button removing it from the first div. on the next click the class shall be removed from the second div and switched to the third.

If there's no more divs, it should go back adding it to the first one.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your HTML markup is not the best one. I would recommend you to use the class "active" for the active slide and hide the others when not visible.

Comment: yes but, apart from the html? :)

Comment: Is a lot of work for an answer. I'm afraid. Why don't you just use any slider plugin for this purpose?